# get address of an EC2 agent from a Jenkins pipeline for git push/scp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a simple Jenkins pipeline, with a stage running on an AWS EC2 agent.

```
pipeline {
  agent none 
  stages {
    stage('Prepare') {
      agent { label 'master' }
      steps {
        sh "touch somefile"
        stash includes: "somefile", name:"ARTIFACT"
      }
    }
    stage('AWS') {
      agent { label 'aws' }
      steps {
        unstash 'ARTIFACT'
        sh "cat somefile"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Stash/unstash works for simple files, but ideally I'd like direct ssh connection so that I can push a git repo onto the slave, and maybe scp a directory. My simple issue is I don't know the public DNS/IP of the slave started by the EC2 plugin so can't connect.

I guess I could figure that out via extra scripts and installing AWS CLI on my Jenkins boxes. Also I've seen suggestions to use S3 and CodeDeploy to push anything onto the instances..however this seems more convoluted than I want at least initially.

I've also seen hints to use instance metadata and http requests to get the IP/DNS (  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html#configuring-instance-metadata-options ) - again looks way more complicated than I'd expect (maybe because I'm a newbie on aws;), so I think/hope I'm not on the right track there.

Was also thinking of adding an extra stage on the aws agent, just to login and do something like "ip addr show" , and pass that back to the pipeline so that a subsequent step could use that for "git push" or scp, etc..

I would have assumed the Jenkins EC2 plugin already knows the IP/DNS to the slave otherwise it couldn't connect itself.

So it would be great to hear about a more straightforward and robust solution.

Comment: `stash`/`unstash` can work with full directory trees and this is what we use. Can you explain where it doesn't meet your expectations?

Comment: Good point, I was guessing it can be (ab?)used for bigger things - just saw some comments elsewhere "assuming it's not too big it's ok".. My only technical reason to connect via ssh is I'd prefer not copying a full directory tree again and again but use git push (or rsync) to generate minimal traffic. Thanks for the hint though.

Answer (score 1):

Get ec2 public ip from metadata via curl.

```
stage('AWS') {
  agent { label 'aws' }
  steps {
    unstash 'ARTIFACT'

    cmd = '''curl --fail --noproxy '*' http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4'''
    public_ip = sh(script:cmd, returnStdout:true).trim()

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know it's easier to get the metadata than I thought (I tried something like this but didn't work - so I started to get lost in documents on how to configure metadata via AWS CLI,etc).  
So now that it works out of the box, you think best way is to have a pipeline stage where I extract it, then leave the instance , do the push to that IP, then another aws stage where I actually do the work on the instance?
At least it would be nice to store this info somewhere on the jenkins side so that it'd have to be done only once.Well I guess ideally the EC2 plugin should take care of it